# Why is property "Name" in Roblox doesn't exist as "Name" like "ClassName" in code

Tags: roblox

I saw code example in Roblox api and class "Name" wasn't used as "[Name](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/property/Instance/Name)" in code like "[ClassName](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/property/Instance/ClassName)" do. Can you tell me the reason?

example:
(ClassName code)

```
 for _, child in ipairs(game.Workspace:GetChildren()) do
    if child.ClassName == "Part" then
        print("Found a Part")
        -- will find Parts in model, but NOT TrussParts, WedgeParts, etc
    end
end
```

(Name code)

```
    local baseplate = workspace.Baseplate
local baseplate = workspace["Baseplate"]
local baseplate = workspace:FindFirstChild("BasePlate")
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so a ClassName is basically like a 'Type' if that makes sense. Name is to narrow down the actual **NAME** of the part. So lets say I have a workspace directory that looks like this:

Workspace:

- CoolPart
- AnotherPart

If I do:

```lua
for _, child in ipairs(game.Workspace:GetChildren()) do
    if child.ClassName == "Part" then
        print("Found a Part")
    end
end
```

It will print 'Found a Part' twice, because both CoolPart and AnotherPart are a Part (not a truss, not a wedge, an actual brick part) of the workspace, but if you do:

```lua
for _, child in ipairs(game.Workspace:GetChildren()) do
    if child.Name == "Part" then
        print("Found a Part")
    end
end
```

It won't print anything, because of everything that is in workspace, none of them are actually titled 'Part', you get what I mean?

Comment: Your example really nicely illustrates your point, but your explanation likens a ClassName to a type, which as a simile is fine, but is technically inaccurate. Roblox instances are a 'userdata' type, but that's not relevant to the answer.  It may be clearer to say that the ClassName field refers to the name of the object's class, and by default new Instances are named after their class.  But as your example points out, an object's Name and ClassName aren't always the same.

Comment: @Kylaaa You are right, thanks for clarifying. It got downvoted because before, it wasn't an answer, it was me asking the OP to send what he was reading, though a upvote from you would neutralize it, if you would.

Comment: Sure thing. In the future, you should leave things like that as a comment on the original question.

Comment: @Kylaaa Would've been able to do that if I had 50 reputation

Answer (score 0):

A truss part is different from a part as a ball is just a part with it's shape property changed. This is *NOT* the same for a truss part. A truss part, although a base part, is not a part. If you do want to do what you did, use:

```
for _, child in ipairs(game.Workspace:GetChildren()) do
    if child:IsA("BasePart) then
        print("Found a Part")
    end
end
```

You should also probably use  `if Instance:IsA("BasePart") then...` because it prompts / shows what you could use.